# What's the best way to change values of List objects?

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming

I have a function that saves an objects, i need to get the new id, set this id in all objects of a list and save the list's objects.

I came from OO and i'm trying to do the best to reach functional paradigm...so to not violate the immutable 'rule', i was thinking on two approaches:

- create a new list and define the id on constructor, call the function that persists on db;
- change the function signature to receive a id and use this id to persists on db;

What is the best approach?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, here is one way of doing it.

For example you have a list of Person objects

```
case class Person( id : Int, name : String, age : Int) 

val persons : List[Person]
```

Now if you want to set id=100 for all persons you can just use a map and copy on the case class.

```
val changedPersons = persons.map( p => p.copy(id) )
```

Note `changedPersons` is a new list that you can then save or do whatever else you want to do with it.

Comment: Nice! But i receive an object on my function..is it correct to change values of this object? If i do it, i could create some side effects, right?

Comment: It depends if the object you receive is immutable or not. If its a `case class` then you cannot change that particular instance of the object. You will have to modify a copy of it. If the object is mutable you will have to make sure that the modification you is thread-safe i.e., more than one thread cannot modify this mutable data structure.